# How to add a .php file to WordPress

Tags: php, pages, page-template

I have a php file in my server (say  www.example.com/up/up.php). If i access that file through the url, my site says no page found. but i want to call that php file using url parameter. I want to call that file to a download file using url access( say www.example.com/up/up.php?f=207).
can someone help me how to do this. as usual i searched fr few days for my problem and came here when i totally cornered.

my up.php contains the following code

```
<?php /* Template Name: Upload */ ?>


<?php
  $app_id = "12345678901234567890";
  $app_secret = "12345678901234567890";
  $post_login_url = "www.mysite.com";
  $album_id = "7777";
  $photo_url = "URL";
  $photo_caption = "cool pics";

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
  if (!$code){ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
      . "client_id=" .  $app_id
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      .  "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
      . "'</script>");
  } else {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
      . "client_id=" . $app_id
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
      . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
      . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // POST to Graph API endpoint to upload photos
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
      . $album_id . "/photos?"
      . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
      . "&message=" . urlencode($photo_caption)
      . "&method=POST"
      . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

    echo '<html><body>';
    echo file_get_contents($graph_url);
    echo '</body></html>';
  }
?>
```

I should pass a value to the url by using link

Comment: You should be able to do it, just provide the full path to the file when you call it.

Comment: @Jared I gave the full url but it ends up with no page found error....should i add any codes to function.php about this external file??

Comment: Well where are you placing the file, in your active theme's folder?

Comment: @Jared I placed it in my serever.
www.mysite.com/up/up.php

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you try to call this file?

Comment: @Jared it just ends up with redirecting to another page. it is supposed to upload and then to redirect. But it just redirecting alone.

Comment: I think that is another question on it's own, probably more suitable for the StackOverflow community since it has to do with Facebook's code and not WordPress.

Comment: @Jared posted the Q in stackoverflow. I wanna know onething, can i access .php file (up.php not up) from wordpress???
if i could, i will finish this work myself.

Comment: Well I think it would work the same way even if you had the `.php` extension. I think it may be a conflict with your rewrite rules possibly, because I've never had a problem accessing a PHP file inside WP with the path to the file.

Comment: @Jared But i saw some site that they are using .php extension for this work and they passed the value via url and it worked.So i too should create a .php file and then i ahve to pass the value. could yu help me out???
I am so sick of searching, I spend a whole week in searching. All i am having is time and i am wasting that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is this:

Put `up.php` in your active theme's folder, and put this line at the top of your `up.php` file:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Up */ ?>
```

Create a page called Up in your WordPress Dashboard, then on the right side of the edit page screen, set the Template to 'Up'.

Depending on what you are doing with this file, you may need to add more code to make it completely secure, but this should at least solve the problem of you being able to access/use that file.

Read the relevant WordPress Codex page for more information:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: gonna try it rite away :)

Comment: @Felix Let me know if it works!

Comment: i can acces the php page now but the code is not working. I used that code in my theme file (single.php) and it worked. but its not working now. should i add any extra code for that???
BTW the php file contain <?php /* Template Name: Up */ ?>
<?php code lines ?>

Comment: @Felix I would need to see the entire `up.php` file in order to see where the problem is. Can you update your question with it?

Comment: @Felix By the way, you would then access the file using the page URL and not the URL to the PHP file. For example, if your page slug was `up`, you would use it like this: `http://yoursite.com/up?f=207`

Comment: i tried by putting the full url in dat URL place for the purpose of checking.so i dint want to pass the valuse.but still it dint work

Comment: sorry i dont know how to put the code in fromat :( 
it is so messy

Comment: i tried by putting the full url in dat URL place for the purpose of checking.so i dint want to pass the valuse.but still it dint work

Comment: @Felix Can you explain what it does to make you determine that it's not working? I tried it on localhost and the file was being called properly (but had errors in the code).

Comment: it wont work for you.It is a php code for uploading picture to the facebook user from a site after registering our app on FB. so it need apdi code n secret code to work.
i used that code in my theme template file (single.php) by giving a value to the URL and it worked. But now its not workin when i place it aside.

Comment: @Felix You may need to include `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your file, try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: :( no use of thad head and footer

Comment: That code still works if i put it in my template file. checked thrice now :(
but dunno why its ot working in up.php
i guess i should create a stand alone PHP file away from the wordpress and call it

Answer (score 1):

I have Found a way which I use regularly to add my own created PHP to a PHP PAGE or post through the use of Short Codes.
Now Create a PHP page named example.php in your theme root directory.
write something like:

```
<?php
echo "Hi! I am a PHP File in Wordpress template Folder!"
?>
```

Now add the following code to your functions.php

```
function exampleFormInclude()
{
include( 'example.php' );
}
function exampleapp_func() {

ob_start();

exampleFormInclude();

$output = ob_get_contents();;
ob_end_clean();

return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'exampleapp', 'exampleapp_func' );
```

Now add shortcode [exampleapp] in your page or post.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a page custom-page.php and 
save it under your theme directory. 
Now,

write the following line at the top of the page

2.`<?php /* Template Name: Custom Page */ ?>`

3.Write your PHP code under the custom page definition line, you can call your other WP template, functions inside this file.

Start like

4.`<?php require_once("header.php");?>` 
or

5.whatever way you are integrating your header and footer to keep the layout consistent.

6.Since this is a custom page, you NEED TO CREATE A PAGE from WordPress admin panel.
Go to Admin => Pages => Add New

7.Add a page title, depending upon how you have coded the custom page, you might add page body (description) as well. You can fully skip the description if it’s written in the custom php page.

8.At right hand side, select Template.
Choose My Custom Page from the dropdown.
You are all set! Go to the slug (permalink) created by wordpress and see the page.